# Ethernet interface drivers (e1000 and NE2000)

Tags: ethernet

What's the difference between e1000 NIC driver and NE2000 NIC driver?? I have tried to find out the answer on google but not been able to completely understand the difference

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NE2000 http://www.intel.com/support/network/adapter/pro100/sb/CS-032516.htm

Answer (score 1):

Difference is they support different network card.